# screen.blit error in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make arrow keys movement in pygame but screen.blit isn't working :/
it keeps coming with a error saying

```
>###AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'blit'
```

here is my code:

```
import sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import * 
pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption(" Arrow keys to move ")

#Colour Defintions
white = pygame.Color(255,255,255)
black = pygame.Color( 0, 0 ,0)
gray = pygame.Color(90, 90, 90)
silver = pygame.Color( 200, 200, 200)
red = pygame.Color( 200, 0 , 0)
blue = pygame.Color(0, 255, 0)

#screen size
size = width, height = 1024, 640

velocity = [5, -20]

screen = pygame.display.set_mode

sprite = pygame.image.load("sprite01.png")

spriterect = sprite.get_rect()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if pressed_keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        spriterect = spriterect.move(5, 0)
    if pressed_keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        spriterect = spriterect.move(-5, 0)
    if pressed_keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        spriterect = spriterect.move(0, 5)
    if pressed_keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        spriterect = spriterect.move(0, -5)

    if spriterect.top < 0:
        spriterect.top = 0
    if spriterect.bottom > height:
        spriterect.bottom = height
        screen.blit(sprite(0, 0))
    screen.blit(spriterect(0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(120)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've missed the parentheses on your set_mode call, so are referencing a function rather than the return value from calling that function.

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode
```

Should be:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
```